# Wordpress Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, wordpress

I am getting the following error message when I try to access one of the links on the blog on my Wordpress site:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/insuranc/public_html/wp-content/themes/inovado/single.php on line 118

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<!-- Title Bar -->  
<?php if ( $data['select_blogtitlebar'] == 'Image' ) { ?>

    <div id="alt-title" class="post-thumbnail" style="background-image: url( <?php echo $data['media_blogtitlebar']; ?> );">
        <div class="grid"></div>
        <div class="container">
            <h1><?php echo $data['text_blogtitle']; ?><?php if($data['text_titledivider'] != "") { echo $data['text_titledivider']; } ?></h1>
            <?php if($data['text_blogsubtitle']){ echo '<h2>'.$data['text_blogsubtitle'].'</h2>'; } ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php if($data['check_blogbreadcrumbs'] == 0){ ?>
        <div id="alt-breadcrumbs">
            <div class="container">
                <?php minti_breadcrumbs(); ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
    <?php if($data['check_stripedborder']) { ?><div class="hr-border"></div><?php } ?>

<?php } elseif ($data['select_blogtitlebar'] == 'No Titlebar') { ?>

        <?php if($data['check_blogbreadcrumbs'] == 0){ ?>
        <div id="no-title">
            <div class="container">

                    <div id="breadcrumbs" class="sixteen columns <?php if(get_post_meta( get_option('page_for_posts'), 'minti_subtitle', true )){ echo 'breadrcumbpadding'; } /* to align middle */ ?>">
                        <?php  minti_breadcrumbs(); ?>
                    </div>

            </div>
        </div>
            <?php if($data['check_stripedborder']) { ?><div class="hr-border"></div><?php } ?>
        <?php } else { ?>
            <div id="no-title-divider"></div>
            <?php if($data['check_stripedborder']) { ?><div class="hr-border"></div><?php } ?>
        <?php } ?>

<?php } else { ?>

    <div id="title">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="ten columns">
                <h1><?php echo $data['text_blogtitle']; ?><?php if($data['text_titledivider'] != "") { echo $data['text_titledivider']; } ?></h1>
                <?php if($data['text_blogsubtitle']){ echo '<h2>'.$data['text_blogsubtitle'].'</h2>'; } ?>
            </div>
                <?php if($data['check_blogbreadcrumbs'] == 0){ ?>
                <div id="breadcrumbs" class="six columns <?php if($data['text_blogsubtitle']){ echo 'breadrcumbpadding'; } /* to align middle */ ?>">
                    <?php minti_breadcrumbs(); ?>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php if($data['check_stripedborder']) { ?><div class="hr-border"></div><?php } ?>

<?php } ?>
<!-- End: Title Bar -->

<div id="page-wrap" class="container">

    <div id="content" class="<?php echo $data['select_blogsidebar']; ?> twelve columns single">

        <?php if (have_posts()) : while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>

            <?php get_template_part( 'framework/inc/post-format/single', get_post_format() ); ?>

            <?php if($data['check_sharebox'] == true) { ?>
                <?php get_template_part( 'framework/inc/sharebox' ); ?>
            <?php } ?>

            <?php if($data['check_authorinfo'] == true) { ?>
            <div id="author-info" class="clearfix">
                    <div class="author-image">
                        <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url(get_the_author_meta( 'ID' )); ?>"><?php echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta('user_email'), '35', '' ); ?></a>
                    </div>   
                    <div class="author-bio">
                        <h4><?php _e('About the Author', 'minti'); ?></h4>
                        <?php the_author_meta('description'); ?>
                    </div>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>

            <?php if($data['check_relatedposts'] == true) { ?>  

            <div id="related-posts">
                    <?php
                    //for use in the loop, list 5 post titles related to first tag on current post
                    $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);
                    if ($tags) {
                    ?>

                      <h3 class="title"><span><?php _e('Related Posts', 'minti'); ?></span></h3>

                      <ul>
                    <?php  $first_tag = $tags[0]->term_id;
                      $args=array(
                        'tag__in' => array($first_tag),
                        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
                        'showposts'=>3
                       );
                      $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
                      if( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
                        while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post(); ?>
                          <li><a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?> <span>(<?php the_time(get_option('date_format')); ?>)</span></a></li>
                          <?php
                        endwhile;
                        wp_reset_query();
                      }
                    }
                    ?>
                     </ul>
            </div>

            <?php } ?>

        <div class="comments"><? php comments_template(); ?></div>

        <div class="post-navigation">
            <div class="alignleft prev"><?php previous_post_link('%link', 'Prev Post', FALSE); ?></div>
            <div class="alignright next"><?php next_post_link('%link', 'Next Post', FALSE); ?> </div>
        </div>

        <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

    </div>

<?php get_sidebar(); ?>

</div>

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a space between the **`<?`** and the `php` .. Remove it on **Line 118**

```
<? php comments_template(); ?></div>.
  ^----- Remove this.
```

Comment: The second `id="breadcrumbs"` is in the `else` branch. So only one gets sent to the browser